# In Stata, how to avoid negative values of lower confidence interval of proportion?

Tags: confidence-interval, stata, proportion

I'm trying to get the CI of a proportion in Stata. Starting with some reproducible example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

tab foreign                     // for proportion

* some dummy categorical variables
gen expen = price > 6165        // strata
la de expen 0 "Cheap" 1 "Expensive"
la val expen expen
tab expen

gen mpg_cat = mpg > 21          // categories for proportion
la de mpg_cat 0 "Low mpg " 1 "High mpg"
la val mpg_cat mpg_cat
tab mpg_cat

tab foreign mpg_cat if expen == 0, col
```

I was trying to hijack logistic regression & margins to give me CI for proportion, however I get the negative value of LCI:

```
. logit foreign i.mpg_cat if expen == 0


Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =         52
                                                LR chi2(1)        =       6.00
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0143
Log likelihood = -26.243758                     Pseudo R2         =     0.1025

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     mpg_cat |
   High mpg  |   1.673976   .7359801     2.27   0.023      .231482    3.116471
       _cons |  -2.079442   .6123724    -3.40   0.001    -3.279669   -.8792136
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. eststo mpg_cat_0: margins mpg_cat, post

Adjusted predictions                            Number of obs     =         52
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(foreign), predict()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     mpg_cat |
   Low mpg   |   .1111111   .0604812     1.84   0.066    -.0074299    .2296521
   High mpg  |         .4   .0979796     4.08   0.000     .2079635    .5920365
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Should I resort to using `ci` command instead?

```
. eststo mpg_cat_0: bysort mpg_cat: ci proportions foreign if expen == 0, exact

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-> mpg_cat = Low mpg

                                                         -- Binomial Exact --
    Variable |        Obs  Proportion    Std. Err.       [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |         27    .1111111    .0604812        .0235275    .2915869

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-> mpg_cat = High mpg

                                                         -- Binomial Exact --
    Variable |        Obs  Proportion    Std. Err.       [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |         25          .4    .0979796        .2112548    .6133465
```

Comment: The `ci` syntax uses the name  `exact`, which is in some ways unfortunate . The Wilson or Jeffreys intervals usually behave very well. Discussion and references within http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rci.pdf (which is accessible to all).

Answer (score 4):

`margins` is a very general purpose command. This is great in that you can use the same command for many situations, but often you can get a bit more out of a special purpose program. What `margins` does is use the delta method to approximate the standard error, which assumes that the sampling distribution for our proportion is normal, i.e. can take values from -infinity to +infinity. That is where the impossible bounds for the confidence interval come from. `ci` uses techniques designed specifically for proportions, so they will conform to the 0-1 bounds.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of hack using the [logit transform](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rproportion.pdf#page=6). I probably have the degrees of freedom slightly wrong:

```
qui logit foreign i.mpg_cat if expen == 0
scalar v = e(N)-e(k)
qui margins, by(mpg_cat) post
qui levelsof mpg_cat
foreach v in `r(levels)' {
    local ME : label mpg_cat `v'
    di "`ME' 95% CI: [" %9.7f ///
        invlogit(ln(_b[`v'.mpg_cat]/(1-_b[`v'.mpg_cat]))-invttail(scalar(v),0.025)*_se[`v'.mpg_cat]/(_b[`v'.mpg_cat]*(1-_b[`v'.mpg_cat]))) ///
        ", " ///
        invlogit(ln(_b[`v'.mpg_cat]/(1-_b[`v'.mpg_cat]))+invttail(scalar(v),0.025)*_se[`v'.mpg_cat]/(_b[`v'.mpg_cat]*(1-_b[`v'.mpg_cat]))) ///
        "]"
}
```

It produces less ridiculous CIs:

```
Low mpg 95% CI: [0.0352280, .29967771]
High mpg 95% CI: [0.2269050, .60227194]
```

Compare that to your output from `ci`:

```
[.0235275, .2915869]
[.2112548, .6133465]
```