# Confidence Interval of a bounded variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Given a random variable $X$ which can take values on $[0,1]$.
I am interested in calculating the confidence values for the mean estimator. 
We know that the mean is normally distributed and can calculate the regular confidence value, but they lie outside of $[0,1]$. How do you deal with this do you intersect the confidence value with the range $[0,1]$?

Comment: Mean in this case is proportion, so a proportion CI.

Comment: Great. if you make it an answer i can accept it.

Comment: @user2974951 In what sense would that mean be a "proportion"?  There aren't any counts involved here.

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357843, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21854 (concerning proportions, btw), https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223507 (also proportions).

Comment: @whuber I don't know, but we can pretend it is.

Comment: @user2974951 That requires justification which doesn't appear to be present in the information given.  After all, we can pretend the moon is a small ball of green cheese, but that won't help us design a rocketship to take us there.  In the present case, if the values of $X$ really are proportions, then they have variances that depend on those proportions (as well as on the underlying sample sizes), which will strongly influence the choice of confidence interval procedure.